# Is it possible to store the data value,value pair in javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I want store the data dynamically in java script like below format. anyone know how it will be done?

```
[{iKey={i3=i3Value, i2=i2Value, i1=i1Value}, 
sKey={s2=s2Value, s1=s1Value, s3=s3Value}}]
```

where i1 ,i2 ,i3,s1,s2 and s3 also **dynamic values** not like"i3"=xyz format.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript objects certainly do support that, both the key and value of the object can be variables. Using the syntax `{[key]: value}` For example:

```
var key = 'key1';
var value = 'value1';
var obj = { [key]: value }; // {key1: "value1"}
```

Specifically using `[key]` allows you to use the value of the variable `key`, rather than in the case of `key: value`, where it uses the actual name `key`.

Comment: You should mention that this is ES2015 syntax and still has a limited support

Comment: i prefer the syntax var obj = {}; obj[key] = value as @Harpreet Singh mentionned

Answer (score 1):

one with not limited support.

```
var key = 'key1';
var value = 'value1';

//How to dynamically add key and value to a Object
var obj = {}
obj[key] = value
```

**where i1 ,i2 ,i3,s1,s2 and s3 also dynamic values not like"i3"=xyz format.**

```
var sampleInput = ['i1', 'i2', 'i3', 's1', 's2', 's3']

var _output = {}
for(var i=0;i<sampleInput.length;i++) {
    _output[sampleInput[i]] = sampleInput[i] + "value"
}
```

**Sample output**

```
Object {i1: "i1value", i2: "i2value", i3: "i3value", s1: "s1value", s2: "s2value"…}
```

Comment: Thank for giving reply,but in key place I want dynamic data

Comment: @suresh It is already creating object dynamically. Please explain what else you want